# Unit test errors undefined method `rank' for 1:Fixnum

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, error-handling

I'm having a problem with my code, and ca't seem to figure out what I need to change. Here are my three files, and at the bottom is the error that I am getting.I have the exact same code 18 times, and half of them give me this error.

initializing the rank, suit, and symbols

```
def initialize(the_rank, the_suit) 
  @rank = the_rank  
  @suit = the_suit  
  @symbols = [nil, nil, '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']  
end
```

new file Pokerhand.rb:
require "./Constants"
require "./Card"
require "./Deck"
require "./CardSpaceship"

```
class PokerHand < Deck
  include Constants
  attr_reader :hand_type

  def initialize(the_cards)
    @cards = [ ]
    @hand_type = UNCLASSIFIED
  for card in the_cards
     @cards << card
  end
  end

    # Straight
  elsif @cards[0].rank == @cards[1]+1.rank &&
    @cards[1].rank == @cards[2]+1.rank &&
    @cards[2].rank == @cards[3]+1.rank &&
    @cards[3].rank == @cards[4]+1.rank   

    @hand_type = STRAIGHT

  end
 end
```

new file test2.rb:

```
class PokerHand < Deck
  include Constants
  attr_reader :hand_type

      def initialize(the_cards)
    @cards = [ ]
    @hand_type = UNCLASSIFIED
  for card in the_cards
     @cards << card
  end
  end


# Determine hand type of PokerHand object.
def classify

  @cards.sort!



  # Straight
 def test_7
    arr7 = [Card.new(2, "C"), Card.new(3, "S"),
         Card.new(4, "H"), Card.new(5, "D"),
         Card.new(6, "S")]
    ph7 = PokerHand.new(arr7)
    ph7.classify
    assert_equal STRAIGHT , ph7.hand_type
  end
```

getting error:

```
 TestClass#test_7:
NoMethodError: undefined method `rank' for 1:Fixnum
    PokerHand.rb:79:in `classify'
    test2.rb:76:in `test_7'
```

Comment: In many systems the cards are expressed like `2D`, `3C`, ... `TH`, `AS` where `T` stands for 10 to keep them all consistently two letter strings.

Comment: You can also test for a straight flush like this: `@cards.map(&:suit).uniq.length == 1` which means they all have the same suit. For sequential cards you should sort on `rank`. The only way your "straight flush" code here works is if you have five of exactly the same card.

Comment: I fixed my code and 1/3 of them are fine, but the others give same error

Comment: `1.rank` is not implemented in your code.

Comment: that solved the problem thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

For a start, your `PokerHand#initialize` method is extremely confused. You never assign any value to `@cards` other than `[ ]`, an empty array. Thus, when you call your `classify` method, `@cards` is still `[ ]`, so `@cards[0]`, `@cards[1]`, or indeed, `@cards[x]` for any value of `x`, will always be `nil`. `PokerHand#initialize` should look more like this:

```
def initialize(cards)
  @cards = cards
  @hand_type = UNCLASSIFIED
end
```

Second, your logic for what constitutes a straight flush is incorrect. Currently, you count a straight flush only if every card in the hand is exactly the same, that is, five copies of the three of hearts, for example.

Comment: would it be  @cards[3].rank == @cards[4]+1.rank  or  @cards[3].rank == @cards[4].rank +1

Comment: Neither, since the sorted cards will sort from smallest to biggest, so it's `@cards[3].rank == @cards[4].rank - 1`

Comment: I fixed my code and 1/3 of them are fine, but the others give same error